# Skip tests while excluding suite tests with Maven

Tags: maven, junit, integration-testing

I am running my maven tests but facing issues with the following duirng integration tests.

1. I want to skips tests,
2. but wanted to include the same test as part of Suite Class.

The reason is that my Suite brings all my rest services using jetty in Suite Class. So at the end of it I can close the server.

Can someone throw some light on it?

Comment: Could you clarify your post ? Do you want to skip _specific_ tests from being executed ?

Comment: Yes, but i want  them to be part of the suite execution.